# Getting "OK Google" to play music from non-downloaded songs in Google Play Music Library?

Tags: google-play-services, music-player, google-pixel

I have many songs uploaded to my Music library on Google Play Music, but don't download more than a few of them to my Google Pixel.

When I say "Ok Google, play _____", my phone will instead try to play a related station from the app, before stopping and saying that option is for subscribers only, of which I am not. Is there a way to get the Pixel to directly stream it from my Music Library where I've uploaded my owned music via voice command, and not the music station in the app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't Subscribe either and I'm having the same issue. It started about a month ago. Before that OK Google would do exactly as NFG requests:
Me: OK Google, Play Foo Fighters Run
Pixel: Playing Foo Fighters Run
Play Music app opens and Foo Fighters Run plays